# Why does my code result in a zip that can't be extracted?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Edit: I have edited the Java code so that it can generate the zip file, but when it is downloaded through the UI, it does not seem to work, and the errors mentioned below are present.

I recently made a code that should make a list of files into a zip file and download it in the browser after sending an AJAX request but after days of trying, the result is still a zip file that either has:

*An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file*

**or**

*Can not open the file as [zip] archive. Is not archive.*

I hope someone can tell me where I got it wrong?

Here is the ajax for the code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/xml",
                    data: xmlString,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
                                var filename = "";
                                var disposition = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("content-disposition");
                                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf("attachment") !== -1) {
                                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                                        filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, "");
                                    }
                                }
                                var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                                var link = document.createElement("a");
                                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                link.setAttribute("download", filename);
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                link.remove();
                            },
                    error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    }
});
```

And here is the java code that will handle the request:

```
File path = new File(fullPath);
if(path.exists() && !path.isDirectory()) { path.delete(); }
      File[] files = path.listFiles((dir, name) -> filesToDownload.contains(name));
if (files.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No files in path " + path.getAbsolutePath());
                }
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fullPath+"download.zip");
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
for (File zipThis : files) {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipThis);
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipThis.getName());
zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
int length;
while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
}
fis.close();
}
zipOut.close();
fos.close();
fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fullPath+"download.zip"));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"));
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "download.zip");
headers.setContentLength(fileBytes.length);
return new ResponseEntity<>(fileBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Here's me hoping someone can tell me what I've done wrong

Comment: `status=="OK"` doesn't do what you think it does. `status.equals("OK")` does.

Comment: @rzwitserloot it does add the files since i checked the log and the files are being added, I think the main problem starts with the ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: There are no log statements in your code. Paste what you actually have.

Comment: There is nothing particular about ByteArrayOutputStream that's a problem here.

Comment: There isn't really a problem with the code; it runs fine, but the output doesn't insert the listed files.

Answer (score 0):

### Content-Length

According to http specs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.13)

> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of
> the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section
> 4.4.

So you should try

```
headers.setContentLength(baos.size()); // or .length() idk
return new ResponseEntity<>(baos.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

### Mime-Type application/zip

You should use `application/zip` as Content-Type

```
 headers.setContentType("application/zip");
```

Comment: I edited the code with a new way to generate the zip file but it seems to make the same corrupted zip  file when downloaded. The generated file is okay to extract but the downloaded file isn't

Comment: @kajl16 Is the size of the zip on the server equal to the size that is downloaded by the browser?

Comment: Yes they're the same size. I even used the content-length used in this solution

Comment: I am pretty sure its not a server-client problem. Maybe your browser's OS do not know how to handle ZIP-Files?

Comment: Also: something with you setContentDispositionFormData looks wrong. Form-Data usually is something transported from browser to server. Not the opposite-direction.